# 2 csrss.exe running/cannot kill/not in task manager

Tags: windows-10, csrss.exe

Parent on first: non-existent Process (704)

Second: non-existent parent 952

Access denied
Path: (error opening)
When I "explore" I see pic of file explorer folders

Bring to front: no visible windows found

Performance Graph: shows private bytes about 2.6 mb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am probably just too ignorant to be coherent . I should probably remove the question.

Comment: Hello, start by using full sentences instead of listing a bunch of details with no context. Also, write what the actual problem is, it's not "closing 2 csrss.exe", that's your not working solution, why do you want to close them in the 1st place?